# How add multiple fliters to a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have inventory, status and transaction tables. Transaction has many to one inventory link and inventroy has one to one relation to status.

I am trying to pull all the transaction with check out > 3 sep and inventory which has staus checkout in Django.

I am using following syntax to pull in pyton, it give error

```
   inventory = Inventory.objects.get(status = 2)
   transactions1 = Transaction.objects.filter((checkout_time__gt='2019-09-03') and inventory__in=inventory.id)
```

Comment: You can't use "and" in a Django ORM query, you use a comma "," for multiple lookups.

Comment: transactions1 = Transaction.objects.filter(checkout_time__gt='2019-09-03', inventory__status=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply chain filters if you're looking for an `AND` statemet like this:

`Transaction.objects.filter(checkout_time__gt='2019-09-03', inventory__status=2)`

If you want to be more explicit you can use Django's `Q` object:

```
from django.models import Q
Transaction.objects.filter(Q(checkout_Time__gt='2019-09-03'), Q(inventory__status=2))
```

Using django's Q object you can build `OR` queries with `|` operator like this:

```
Transaction.objects.filter(Q(checkout_Time__gt='2019-09-03') | Q(inventory__status=2))
```